# Bluetooth is not working properly on a Dell XPS 15

Tags: dell, bluetooth, connection, xps

I have Dell laptop (xps 15-sandy-bridge). I was using Ubuntu 11.04 and the Bluetooth was working properly. However, once I installed Ubuntu 11.10 the Bluetooth my laptop can detect Bluetooth devices but can not pair connection and can not send/receive files. Can anyone help on this problem?

Comment: I've been looking for a solution for my problem with bluetooth by browsing through ubuntu forum. I've noticed that this problem is not limited to Dell XPS 15, some users of laptops of other brands are facing the same problem after installing ubuntu 11.10. I've tried a number of suggested solutions like updating the Kernel or installing Blueman software or allowing sharing files through bluetooth from network sharing setting but nothing worked.

Comment: Post the output of: lsusb

Comment: Also try 
sudo apt-get remove bluez
sudo apt-get install bluez

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!